# d3.js and geo projections albers/centers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

Below is a bit of code that I've written and I'm hoping someone can help me out and explain why it's not responding the way I imagined it would.

I have (quite obviously) pieced this together from a number of examples, docs, etc. online and am using d3.v3.js.  I want to better understand exactly what the center, scale, and translate 'attributes' of a projection do, so in addition to the large quantity of reading I've done, I thought I'd write a brief script that allows the user to click a new 'center' for the map - so in effect, you should be able to click this map (made with some data available in the gallery) and recenter the map on a new state/location/etc.

The issue is that every time I set a new center for the data as the inversely projected point that was clicked (that is, invert the point to get the new coordinates to set the center to), the map centers on alaska, then I can click that general area a few times and the world 'rotates' back into view.

What am I doing wrong?  I thought this script would help me gain a better understanding of what's going on, and I'm getting there, but I would like a little help from you if at all possible.

```
<script>
var w = 1280;
var h = 800;

var proj = d3.geo.albers();                                                                    

var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(proj); 

var svg = d3.select("body")                                                                    
            .insert("svg:svg")                                                                 
               .attr("height", h)                                                              
               .attr("width", w);                                                              

var states = svg.append("svg:g")                                                               
                  .attr("id", "states");                                                       
d3.json("./us-states.json", function(d) {                                                      
   states.selectAll("path")                                                                    
      .data(d.features).enter()                                                                
         .append("svg:path")                                                                   
            .attr("d", path)                                                                   
            .attr("class", "state");                                                           
});

svg.on("click", function() {
   var p = d3.mouse(this);                                                                     
   console.log(p+" "+proj.invert(p));                                                          
   proj.center(proj.invert(p));
   svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);                                                      

});   

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use projection.rotate()

```
svg.on("click", function() {
    p = proj.invert(d3.mouse(this));
   console.log(p);                                                          
   proj.rotate([-(p[0]), -(p[1])]);
   svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);

});
```

Comment: Elijah - that did not seem to help...why would we have rotated this rather than recentered on the point in question?